# Bower Install Resolution Not Following bower.json Configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

[image]

Image really says it all - I am trying to install a particular version of angular-bootstrap. When I run:

```
bower install angular-bootstrap#0.13.0 --save
```

it prompts me for the resolution answer, which I have already provided with the `!` persist-changes attribute. My bower.json is updated with the resolution, and I can manually install the correct library by manually answering this prompt in command line, but it SHOULDN'T be prompting me since there is a specified resolution. What am I missing?

End goal is to have `bower install` install the correct version without prompt.

Edit: Entire `bower.json` file. Only change is project name:

```
{
  "name": "fooBar",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-animate": "1.3.x",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.13.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-duallistbox": "~0.0.3",
    "angular-bootstrap-select": "~0.0.3",
    "angular-bootstrap-switch": "x.x.x",
    "angular-cookies": "1.3.x",
    "angular-dynamic-locale": "~0.1.27",
    "angular-flot": "~0.0.13",
    "angular-google-analytics": "x.x.x",
    "angular-gridster": "~0.10.7",
    "angular-i18n": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-intro.js": "~1.1.4",
    "angular-loading-bar": "x.x.x",
    "angular-local-storage": "x.x.x",
    "angular-messages": "~1.3.13",
    "angular-moment": "~0.8.2",
    "angular-ngautocomplete": "~1.0.0",
    "angular-peity": "~0.0.2",
    "angular-resource": "1.3.x",
    "angular-route": "1.3.x",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.3.2",
    "angular-signalr-hub": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-translate": "~2.4.0",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "~2.4.0",
    "angular-translate-loader-url": "~2.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "x.x.x",
    "angular-ui-select": "x.x.x",
    "angular-ui-sortable": "0.12.8",
    "angular-validator": "~0.2.5",
    "angular-wizard": "~0.4.0",
    "angular-xeditable": "~0.1.8",
    "angularD3": "~0.0.28",
    "angularjs-geolocation": "~0.1.1",
    "angularjs-nvd3-directives": "~0.0.7",
    "angularjs-toaster": "~0.4.9",
    "a0-angular-storage": "~0.0.9",
    "angular-jwt": "~0.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "x.x.x",
    "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.3",
    "bootstrap-select": "~1.6.2",
    "bootstrap-social": "~4.8.0",
    "Chart.js": "~1.0.2",
    "d3": "~3.5.3",
    "flag-icon-css": "~0.6.4",
    "flow.js": "~2",
    "font-awesome": "~4.2.0",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "jquery-ui": "1.11.1",
    "jspdf": "~1.0.178",
    "lodash": "3.7.0",
    "moment": "x.x.x",
    "ng-clip": "~0.2.2",
    "ng-flow": "~2",
    "ngDraggable": "*",
    "ngImgCrop": "~0.3.2",
    "ngmap": "x.x.x",
    "nvd3": "~1.1.15-beta",
    "PACE": "pace#~1.0.2",
    "rangy-official": "~1.3.0-alpha.20140921",
    "restangular": "x.x.x",
    "signalr": "~2.1.2",
    "stacktrace-js": "~0.6.2",
    "textAngular": "x.x.x",
    "zeroclipboard": "x.x.x",
    "tc-angular-chartjs": "~1.0.12",
    "angular-sweetalert": "latest",
    "angular-touch": "^1.3.13",
    "auth0.js": "6.8.3",
    "auth0-lock": "9.1.4",
    "auth0-angular": "~4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "x.x.x",
    "angular-scenario": "x.x.x",
    "angular-qtip2-directive": "~0.1.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "angular": {
      "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "~2.14"
      }
    },
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": []
    },
    "ngImgCrop": {
      "main": []
    },
    "textAngular": {
      "main": []
    },
    "angular-wizard": {
      "main": [
        "./dist/angular-wizard.css",
        "./dist/angular-wizard.js"
      ]
    },
    "flag-icon-css": {
      "main": [
        "css/flag-icon.min.css",
        "flags/1x1/us.svg",
        "flags/4x3/us.svg",
        "flags/1x1/ru.svg",
        "flags/4x3/ru.svg"
      ]
    },
    "angular-i18n": {
      "main": [
        "angular-locale_en-us.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "x.x.x",
    "angular": "~1.3.x",
    "bootstrap-select": "~1.6.2",
    "d3": "~3.5.3",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.13.0",
    "angular-ui-sortable": "~0.12.8",
    "lodash": "3.7.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have provided the !, you should see something like this in your bower.json:

```
"resolutions": {
   "angular-bootstrap": "0.13.0"
}
```

You could try adding this and see if it still asks for a resolution. If it does, remove the bower_components folder and run a fresh bower install.

Comment: I agree, and it's there, which is why I am surprised it doesn't work. Please see the screenshot.

Comment: which version of bower are you using?

Comment: 1.5.3 //comment length

Comment: I will give it a try.

Comment: The problem persists with updated bower. Upvoting because I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, although you haven't really been helped yet. Haha. Could you paste your entire bower.json?

Comment: Yep, it's in the Q now.

Comment: Well that is strange. I am getting an "unneccessary resolution" with angular-bootstrap. What might help is removing the bower-components folder and just rerunning bower install. Running it fresh works for me :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114062/discussion-between-pkeuter-and-vso).